# Where can I ask my question about classification schemas of human activities?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

My question [Are there popular classification schemas of human activities?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/33900) on [Project Management Stack Exchange](https://pm.stackexchange.com/) has been closed as off-topic. It is about classification of human activities into e.g. Paid/Unpaid, Learn/Apply, IT/Music/Exercise/Others. Is there any Stack Exchange where I can ask this question?

For reference, here is a copy of the original question:

> I am trying to gain insights into how I spend my time professionally
> and personally. I plan to track a large portion of my activities using
> time tracking software and assign classes to each activity from
> multiple mutually independent classification schemas. The schemas are
> designed so that each activity falls into exactly one class of each
> schema.
>
> E.g., currently I am considering these classification schemas
> (excerpt):
>
> Area of life:
>
> - Information technology
>
>   - Software development
>   - Others
> - Music
>
>   - Vocals
>   - Guitar
>   - ...
> - Physical exercise
>
>   - Weight training
>   - Stretching
>   - Cardio
> - ...
>
> Payment:
>
> - Paid
> - Unpaid
>
> Skill stage (cannot find a better name for this):
>
> - Learn
> - Apply
>
> Here are some example activities with their classes:
>
> | Activity | Area of life (Level 1) | Area of life (level 2) | Payment | Skill stage |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Write software at my job | Information technology | Software development | Paid | Apply |
> | Learn new framework at my job | Information technology | Software development | Paid | Learn |
> | Watch guitar tutorial | Music | Guitar | Unpaid | Learn |
>
> By having multiple schemas I avoid the combinatorial explosion I would
> get with only one, and I retain more flexibility for reporting.
>
> - Information technology
>
>   - Software development
>
>     - Paid
>
>       - Learn
>       - Apply
>     - Unpaid
>
>       - Learn
>       - Apply
>   - Others
>
>     - Paid
>
>       - Learn
>       - Apply
>     - ...
> - ...
>
> As usual, the devil is in the details, and thus it is not easy to come
> up with schemas that work for all of my activities. So I wonder
> whether there exist some widely used activity classification schemas
> like these, e.g. de facto standards from popular software, or maybe
> even official ones from standardization organizations. So far, I have
> only found some schemas in research papers, but it seems to me that
> these have been created ad hoc just for these papers:
>
> General purpose:
>
> - https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Classification-of-Activities_tbl1_220413119
> - https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Examples-of-living-activity-classification_fig1_311621874
> - https://www.researchgate.net/figure/2-Generic-Activity-Classification-used-in-CHASE_fig3_265251283
> - https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Classification-of-Activities_tbl1_258957597
> - https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Classification-of-Activities_tbl1_220413119
> - https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Classification-of-activities_tbl1_265223072
> - https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Taxonomy-of-activities-significant-for-the-older-adults-in-SH_tbl1_277918595
>
> Marketing:
>
> - https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Taxonomy-of-work-tasks-motivating-information-seeking_tbl1_262639795
>
> Development of Food Technology:
>
> - https://www.researchgate.net/figure/1-Classification-of-work-tasks_tbl1_323589978

Comment: The question is now deleted, can you please take screenshot of it and link to it, instead of the link to the question?

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar: Thanks for notifying me of that. I have now added a copy of the original question. I hope that is as good or even better than a screenshot.

Comment: @MarcoEckstein even better - thank you for following up on Shadow Wizard's request!

Comment: This question is related to several SEs but you really have to be a full stack guy to really understand how it fits into any one of them so, you will probably get close voted by specialists no matter where you post it.  That said, I think I can answer the underlying question you have.  In time tracking software, we don't use standardized job class lists for very practical UI/UX reasons.  When you create a list of codified tasks, the bigger the list, the less practical it is so, you want it to be specific to the tasks you actually use that time tracking software for.

Comment: This is why most CRMs don't come with pre-built lists, not because the developers are lazy, but because populating a list with 10,000 options reduces efficiency if you only ever use 20 of them.  This is why most CRMs (except for those designed for specific industries) give you the tools to make your own classes instead of trying to make the classes for you. Since the industry standard is to make your own, there is no standard accepted list.

Answer (score 4):

[Philosophy](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) *might* be a good fit. It has a [classification](/questions/tagged/classification) [tag](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/classification), however, I'd consider making the question more abstract first (and removing the noise related to the background of how you came up with it).

Parts of your question might be on-topic *individually* on some sites of the network. For instance, taxonomy of music-related activities *might* be on-topic on [Music Fans](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). They too have a [classification](/questions/tagged/classification) [tag](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/classification) that seems to be applicable in your case.

But as with all advice to post on a specific site of the network, please, take the above with a grain of salt, read the Help Center articles on topicality of each (I linked the suggested ones), and ask on a per-site Meta in case of doubt *before* posting.